# Angular 4 + JavaScript - Simple slideshow didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I put the `<script>` inside a single component, *StartComponent*.

*StartComponent* is in a `<router-outlet>` which inside *Root* or AppComponent.

I've tested this working in a single `index.html` file (Non-Angular or Non-Component based). But I have no idea why it didn't work in Angular 4 (Component based)

**start.component.html** (*StartComponent*)

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var time = 1000;

// Image list
images[0] = 'assets/pictures/kapal02.jpg';
images[1] = 'assets/pictures/kapal01.jpg';
images[2] = 'assest/pictures/truck.jpg';

// Function
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[i];

    if(i < images.length - 1) {
      i++;
    }
    else {
      i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("changeImage()", time);
}

window.onload = changeImage;


<img id="slideshow" src="assets/pictures/kapal02.jpg">
```

Comment: Why would you embed script elements inside your component template? You are not taking full advantage of the framework

Comment: @Dummy what should I do then? where should I put the script?

Comment: I have given you the answer in plunker have a look and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this simple plunker on how to do this in angular2. Please have a look at home.component file. This will give you an idea on how to tackle this in angular2 way.

[Checkout this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oqk3lZIMG8vMutanvidD?p=preview)

Code for home component as below

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  urlVariable:string;
  images:Array<any>
  ngOnInit() {
        var i = 0;
        this.images = [];
        var time = 1000;

        // Image list
        this.images[0] = 'http://i64.tinypic.com/2czam2x.jpg';
        this.images[1] = 'http://i63.tinypic.com/2czanp2.jpg';
        this.images[2] = 'http://i63.tinypic.com/2czaq8k.jpg';

        this.urlVariable = this.images[0];
  }

  setImage(index:number){
     this.urlVariable = this.images[index];
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try, perhaps it takes time for me to respond this.

Comment: No worries take ur time but plunker is just to give you an idea how it works and how to apply binding rather than getting a reference to an element.

Comment: I think I'm going to get it, rather than put the `script` to the `component.html`, I should've put it in `component.ts`

Comment: How about timeInterval?

Comment: It's working but, some of the images aren't showed. It's not time interval, it's randomizer lol, btw thanks.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped u